# Creating Real-Time Video Stream from Image Frames using FFmpeg and Streaming to RTMP URL

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I've been working on a project where I need to continuously convert a series of image frames into a video and stream it to an RTMP URL in real time. I initially tried using FFmpeg with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i ":1" -framerate 30 -i "./image%05d.png" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 25 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -vf "format=yuv420p,scale=1280:720" -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -f flv "rtmps://your_rtmp_url_here"
```

However, I encountered issues when new images were added to the folder in real-time. The solution wasn't as straightforward as I initially thought.

Does anyone have experience with real-time video streaming from dynamically changing image frames using FFmpeg? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!